# How to set next encoding to a file in Java

Tags: java, file, path, stream

Here is my code which is reading file and replacing on a specific line the text but when is reading  the(readAllLines method) lines and it have a symbol in the file which doesn't matches with the specified Charset it throws MalformedInputException. 
For Example: I'm reading a text with UTF_8 charset but in file it has symbol "†" and it throws me MIE.

I would like to ask you how in the following code i can make a check when a MalformedInputException found and try the next encoding . For example when the encoding is UTF_8, to try the next one UTF_16 etc. and when it matches to read the file properly.

```
public boolean replaceTextInSpecificLine(String fileName, int lineNumber, String content, Charset cs)
{
    try
    {

        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        File filePath = readFile(fileName, true);
        List<String> lines = null;
        if(filePath !=null)
        {
           lines = Files.readAllLines(filePath.toPath(), cs);


            while (lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > lines.size() - 1)
            {
                System.out.print("Wrong line number or the file is empty! Enter another line: ");
                lineNumber = scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();
            }
            lines.set(lineNumber - 1, content);
            Files.write(filePath.toPath(), lines, cs);
            System.out.println("Successfully saved!");

            return true;
        }

    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {

       e.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally
    {
        close(scan);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just add `catch(MalformedInputException e)` before `IOException` catching or there where you are reading lines. You can create you own method which switches encoding by given encoding name. And call it whenever it catches MalformedInputException. I suggest you to use `URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");`. You can create list of encoding names which will be called one by one whenever exception will be catched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid switching encodings while reading the file and simply reread the file with the next encoding. Something like this would be sufficient:

```
List<String> getAllLines(File file, Charset... charsets) {
    for (Charset cs: charsets) {
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), cs);
        } catch (MalformedInputException e) {
            ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
    // error
}
```

(this is just an example, your arguments may vary based on need)
If you switched encodings while reading the document, you have the potential of interpreting some characters as valid UTF-8 characters when in fact they were ISO-8859-1 characters.

Comment: My answer above has the framework for what you request.